# xgboost treemethod gpu-hist outperformed by hist using rtx3060ti and amd ryzen 9 5950x

Tags: gpu, cpu, xgboost, hyperparameters

I'm doing some hyper-parameter tuning, so speed is key. I've got a nice workstation with both an `AMD Ryzen 9 5950x` and an `NVIDIA RTX3060ti 8GB`.

Setup:

- `xgboost` `1.5.1` using `PyPi` in an `anaconda` environment.
- `NVIDIA` graphics driver `471.68`
- `CUDA` `11.0`

When training a `xgboost` model using the `scikit-learn` API I pass the `tree_method` = `gpu_hist` parameter. And i notice that it is consistently outperformed by using the default `tree_method` = `hist`.

Somewhat surprisingly, even when I open multiple consoles (I work in `spyder`) and start an `Optuna` `study` in each of them, each using a different `scikit-learn` model until my CPU usage is at `100%`. When I then compare the `tree_method` = `gpu_hist` with `tree_method` = `hist`, the `tree_method` = `hist` is still faster!

How is this possible? Do I have my drivers configured incorrectly?, is my dataset too small to enjoy a benefit from the `tree_method` = `gpu_hist`? (7000 samples, 50 features on a 3 class classification problem). Or is the `RTX3060ti` simply outclassed by the `AMD Ryzen 9 5950x`? Or none of the above?

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Edit @Ferdy:
I carried out this little experiment:

```
    def fit_10_times(tree_method, X_train, y_train):
    times = []
    for i in range(10):
        model = XGBClassifier(tree_method = tree_method)
        start = time.time()
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        times.append(time.time()-start)
    return times

cpu_times = fit_10_times('hist', X_train, y_train)
gpu_times = fit_10_times('gpu_hist', X_train, y_train)

print(X_train.describe())
print('mean cpu training times: ', np.mean(cpu_times), 'standard deviation :',np.std(cpu_times))
print('all training times :', cpu_times)
print('----------------------------------')
print('mean gpu training times: ', np.mean(gpu_times), 'standard deviation :',np.std(gpu_times))
print('all training times :', gpu_times)
```

Which yielded this output:

```
mean cpu training times:  0.5646213531494141 standard deviation : 0.010005875058323703
all training times : [0.5690040588378906, 0.5500047206878662, 0.5700047016143799, 0.563004732131958, 0.5570034980773926, 0.5486617088317871, 0.5630037784576416, 0.5680046081542969, 0.57651686668396, 0.5810048580169678]
----------------------------------
mean gpu training times:  2.0273998022079467 standard deviation : 0.05105794761358874
all training times : [2.0265607833862305, 2.0070691108703613, 1.9900789260864258, 1.9856727123260498, 1.9925382137298584, 2.0021069049835205, 2.1197071075439453, 2.1220884323120117, 2.0516715049743652, 1.9765043258666992]
```

The peak in CPU usage refers to the CPU training runs, and the peak in GPU usage the GPU training runs.
[image: My task manager right after the experiment]

Comment: What is the gpu usage percentage?

Comment: I missed the notification about your question. I will check right now and edit my post with the result.

Comment: discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67081695/3494126

Answer (score 3):

7000 samples is too small to fill the GPU pipeline, your GPU is likely to be starving.  We usually work with millions of samples when using GPU acceleration.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you!